# Is there a way to tell if a particular *-context.xml file has been loaded?

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

I was advised that the proper way to load multiple share customisations was to create a custom bootstrap for it like so:

```
<!-- Provide extensions config -->
<bean id="MyCustomClientConfig" class="org.springframework.extensions.config.ConfigBootstrap" init-method="register">
  <property name="configService" ref="web.config" />
  <property name="configs">
   <list>
    <value>classpath:alfresco/web-extension/mycustom-config.xml</value>
   </list>
  </property>
</bean>
```

However the customisations in my custom share config, specifically making an aspect visible, does not seem to be working.

I'd like to find a log4j debugging key that I can enable or 'turn up' to get more debugging info out, ideally to see if this bootstrap, which is in a *-context.xml file is being loaded.

I'm deploying this code as an AMP if that's relevant, and I've placed the context file in config/alfresco/web-extension

Comment: Quick and dirty way - add a syntax error to the xml file, and make sure the repo blows up on startup...

Comment: Oh dear ;-) Not exactly the kind of debugging I was after... but I'll give it a go anyway, this seems to be the only way I can figure out what's going on in alfresco most of the time :(

Comment: I gave you an upvote Gagravarr; the context file was getting loaded but errors in the custom share config which it referenced don't make any difference at all to share or repo.

Comment: IIRC, you can get spring to tell you about files, but it's a bit fiddly. However, spring checks files for context files very early in the process, so if it'll blow up it'll blow up within 10 seconds. That makes it often the quickest way, nasty as it is...